# Syntax error at or near AS integer when creating a sequence

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-11

I am getting "error at or near AS integer" in below code when I am trying to execute with psql.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.auth_group_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

The above sql statement is from the backup file of local machine postgres version 11 and executing in EC2 postgres version 9.3. I am new to postgres and getting no idea as the sql is generated by postgres only so it should work with psql. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgres 9.3 (which is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)) did not support the `AS data_type` option. This was introduced in version 10.

You could try using `pg_dump` from your 9.3 installation to do the dump, but I am not sure if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Some workaround that works for me. In this case, you simply have to remove `AS integer` from the dump file.

```
sed 's/    AS integer$//g' your_dump_file.out > tmp.out
mv tmp.out your_dump_file.out
```